# JPG user photos not displaying in Drupal 7

Tags: media, users

In D7, when I upload a photo to a user profile page, the image displays if the original extension was a *.png file, but not if it was a *.jpg file. Uploading the files places them in sites/example.org/files/pictures, which indicates that the permissions are correct. But jpg files don't diplay on users' profile or forum posts. Instead the words "username picture" is displayed.

In admin/config/people/accounts, enable user pictures is enabled. However, I did not add a existing image field in admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

Basic page, articles and forum has an image field (field_image), with allowed extensions png, gif, jpg, jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

"username picture" is likely the alt text applied to the image. So it's trying to render an image, but failing because the web server can't find it. If you check the page source, is it trying to show the image with a .png extension instead of .jpg? If not, is the path correct?

If either the extension or the path are wrong, this could be a problem with the template. Perhaps it was hard coded in the past and settings have changed since?